# Узнать формат изображения

Tags: php

Есть скрипт загрузки изображения на сервер:

```
$imgDir = dirname(__FILE__)."/gallery/$us[users_login]/";        // каталог для хранения изображений 
@mkdir($imgDir, 0777);  // создаем, если его еще нет 

// Проверяем, нажата ли кнопка добавления фотографии. 
if (@$_REQUEST['doUpload']) { 
$data = $_FILES['file']; 
$tmp = $data['tmp_name']; 
// Проверяем, принят ли файл. 
if (@file_exists($tmp)) { 
$info = @getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
// Проверяем, является ли файл изображением. 
if (preg_match('{image/(.*)}is', $info['mime'], $p)) { 
  // Имя берем равным текущему времени в секундах, а 
  // расширение - как часть MIME-типа после "image/". 
  $name = "$imgDir/".time().".".$p[1]; 
  // Добавляем файл в каталог с фотографиями. 
  move_uploaded_file($tmp, $name);
  $times = time(); 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo_gallery SET id_us='".$us['users_id']."', time='".$times."', name_foto='".$times."'"); 

} else { 
  echo "<div class='list'>Данный тип файла запрещен для загрузки!</div>"; 
} 
} else { 
echo "<div class='list'>Упс. Ошибка!</div>"; 
} 
}
```

Мне нужно узнать расширение загрузившегося файла.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: 1. *загрузившего* — вероятно, опечатка, и имелось ввиду «загруженного». 2. в запросе к `mysql`, вероятно, ошибка: полю `name_foto`, судя по названию, надо присваивать значение совсем другой переменной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если нужно узнать не *формат* изображения (как написано в заголовке вопроса), а суффикс файла (т.н. «расширение»), то можно воспользоваться, например, функцией `pathinfo()`:

```
$suffix = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

а в приведённом скрипте, кстати, происходит попытка узнать (из информации, переданной браузером) именно *формат* изображения и в блоке `if (preg_match...` он доступен в переменной `$p[1]`.

**дополнение**

информация, полученная из имени файла не очень достоверна, потому что основывается на сведениях, переданных серверу со стороны клиента.

более достоверно — воспользоваться, например, программой `file` (с опцией `--mime-type`), вызвав её с помощью функции `exec()` примерно так:

```
$res = exec("file --mime-type /путь/к/файлу.jpg");
```

если в файле действительно содержится изображение в формате `jpeg`, то она вернёт такую строку:

```
/путь/к/файлу.jpg: image/jpeg
```

---

другой достоверный и универсальный метод: функция [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php):

```
$res = mime_content_type("/путь/к/файлу.jpg");
```

она вернёт результат в виде строки `image/jpeg`.

Answer (score 3):

И расширение файла, и его MIME-тип приходят со стороны клиента и легко могут быть подделаны или просто не верны. Мы используем внешние утилиты для определения типа и параметров именно из содержания загруженных файлов. Запуск внешних команд в php: [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php).

Для изображений подойдёт утилита [`identify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) от пакета ImageMagick:

```
identify FILENAME
// FILENAME JPEG 259x194 259x194+0+0 8-bit sRGB 5.22KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Мы принимаем к загрузке и видео, и аудио и картинки, поэтому процесс определения типа загруженного файла чуть сложнее, и мы сначала задействуем [`ffprobe`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) (идёт вместе с ffmpeg'ом):

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json  -show_format -show_streams  FILENAME
```

Результат – json с описанием того, как видит этот файл ffmpeg. Напр. для картинки JPG он не увидит аудио треков и напишет `"format_name": "image2"`. В случае изображения дополнительно получаем инфу об изображении `identify`'ем, как написал выше. Аудиофайлы – [`sox`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)'ом.

Comment: мне кажется, стоит ещё упомянуть программу `file` и её параметр `--mime-type`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не знал, спасибо! Напишите отдельным ответом – это действительно лучшее решение для ТС.

Comment: добавил в существующий ответ.